# What is the exact meaning of "Now, here comes the music today" in the last paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have read a sentence which I can't interpret exactly. The context is as follows:

> Good morning. The program is about music. The word "music" comes from the Greek word "muse". The Muses are the goddesses of the arts. Music is only one of the arts. It is like the spoken language, but it uses sounds. Today's program brings together music from different corners of the world. Who invented music? Who sang the first song? No one knows exactly the answers to these questions. But we know that music plays an important part in almost everyone's life. Babies and young children love to hear people singing to them. When they are a little older, they like to sing the songs they have heard. When children go to school, their world of music grows. In the middle grades students take music lessons.When they reach high school, they become interested in listening to pop music.
>
> The records we have chosen for you today are from American country music, Indian music, pop music and so on. Music has meaning for everyone. It can make people happy or it can make them sad. In this program we shall study the language of music. We shall be trying to find out more about how music works. We shall try to find out how music says what people feel.
>
> **Now, here comes the music today**. I shall explain why they are all good music…

What is the exact meaning of "Now, here comes the music today" in the last paragraph?

Does it mean "Now, I will play the music I chose today" or "When it comes to the music" or "Now, we are talking about the music..."? Which one is more appropriate?

Comment: The author of that text needs to check his syntax throughout. Where does it come from ?  The closest to making syntactic sense is "Here comes today's (choice/selection of) music"  _bracketed words are optional_ and I think you would have understood my version without any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the meaning is close to your first suggested interpretation. I would word it as:

> ***Now we are about to hear the music we have chosen for today***.

The two-word phrase ***here comes*** is somewhat idiomatic, meaning *"something or someone is arriving at or approaching the place where we all are now."* There's a song often played at weddings that begins with *"Here comes the bride..."* which means, essentially, *"The bride is here!"* Similarly, *"Here comes the bus"* implies the speaker can see (or hear) the bus off in the distance. So, when the speaker says, "Here comes the music today," I interpret that as, "Today's music is about to be heard."

It might be worth noting that the last paragraph isn't very well written. For the most part, "music" is an uncountable noun, so I'd offer this suggested edit:

> I shall explain why they are all good **songs**... (or *compositions*, perhaps)

or:

> I shall explain why **it is** all good music...